# Writing plugin for a jquery function?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, plugins

I'm new and i don't knw how to write plugin. Can anyone help how to write plugin for this jquery function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var offset_1 = $("li.list:first-child").position().left;
    var offset_2 = $("li.list:nth-child(2)").position().left;
    var totalWidth =offset_2-offset_1;


        $("a.abc").click(function() {
            $("#scroller").not(":animated").animate({"scrollLeft":"-="+totalWidth},300);
            return false;
        });
        $("a.def").click(function() {
            $("#scroller").not(":animated").animate({"scrollLeft":"+="+totalWidth},300);
            return false;
        });
});
```

Comment: Did you look at [the introductory plugin tutorial on jQuery.com](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)? Note that the usual syntax for calling a plugin is `$(someSelector).pluginName(paramsHere)` - I'm not sure how that fits with the code you've shown that has several different selectors...

Answer (score 0):

you should have an idea of how it work. design the way people use your plugin.

for sample (just an idea)

```
$('.target').doSomething({
  offset1 : 'li.list:first-child',
  offset2 : 'li.list:nth-child(2)',
  toLeft : 'a.abc',
  toRight : 'a.def'
})
```

then you [create jquery plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)

```
(function($){
    $.fn.doSomething = function(options){
        var offset1 = $(options.offset1).position.left;
        var offset2 = $(options.offset2).position.left;
        var toLeft = $(options.toLeft);
        //... do something
    }
}).(jQuery)
```

Comment: This is not working.I can't give like this it like this as these are not my default options.